# no line numbers in StackTraceElement

Tags: gwt

I added an UncaughtExceptionHandler with the following code:

```
        GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new   
          GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {  
          public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {  

              StackTraceElement[] elements = e.getStackTrace();

              String stackTrace = "";
              for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
              {
                  stackTrace += elements[i] + "\n";
              }

              PlatformServices.instance().log().debug("caught unhandled exception: " + e + " ; Stack:\n" + stackTrace);
          }
        });
```

The problem is that only the function name of each StackTraceElement is valid. All other information is default, such as -1 for line number or unknown for class name.

I wonder if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information may be just unavailable during GWT app execution. Check core `StackTraceElement.java` class, method `toString()`. Value of `lineNumber` is printed out only in case if it is >= zero. And it's not impossible that it can be negative.

My tests with `UncaughtExceptionHandler` gave me exactly same results (no references to line numbers in runtime). When compiled in Obfuscated mode, I couldn't even get the filename, so the output looked like:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'g' of null 
Unknown.iPb(Unknown Source) 
Unknown.gPb(Unknown Source) 
Unknown.npd(Unknown Source) 
...
```

Not really a solution, but at least you are not alone :).

Answer (score 1):

Try to set this in your module file

```
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated" />
```